# stackhash_e8ad exception C++?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm using OpenCV for Video Analytics.

I'm using the following code to convert from Jpeg data to `cv::Mat`.

```
Mat cvFrame(frameSizeY, frameSizeX, CV_8UC3, jpegBuff);
```

The `jpegBuff` is decoded from IP Camera Stream.

The `cvFrame` is using in the program to process Video Analytics.

The problem is sometime The app crash with `Stackhash_e8ad`Exception` as following image

[image]

I guess that the `cvFrame` is fail when create from `jpegBuff`, so It will crash when access cvFrame, but I don't know why, and don't know how to detect when `cvFrame` failed.

Someone can show me how to detect this case, and is there any way to avoid this crash?

Many thanks!

Comment: please run in debug and post the error message

Comment: Thank you! but when I run in debug, this bug is not happen

Comment: Then your buffer is probably not correct. Which is the format of your data in the buffer?